# Webpack 4 code splitting per page for "traditional" website

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, html-webpack-plugin

I am new to webpack and am building a JS application (with just vanilla JS) for a traditional server-side-served-html website.

I am confused about code splitting, common chunks, split chunks, and htmlWebpackPlugin chunks.  I have some things working, but some of my app code is being duplicated in the bundles.

Here's what I am trying to do (leaving out hashes for readability):

```
// ALL pages get this (node_modules stuff)
<script src="/static/vendors.js"></script>

// ALL pages get this (base JS for my app)
<script src="/static/app.js"></script>

// ONLY product pages get this.  This is where I am having problems 
// with modules from app.js getting copied in
<script src="/static/product.js"></script>
```

I have the "vendors" part worked out, I added this to my webpack config:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: { test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/, name: "vendors", chunks: "all" }
        }
    }
},
```

I've also got the conditional inclusion of the product.js bundle on the product page by just including this on the product.html template:

```
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.product.entry %>">
```

And then this in my webpack config:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    template: './src/templates/product.html',
    filename: `${templates}/product.html`,
    chunks: ['app', 'product']
}),
```

That kind of works except for the duplicated code in product.js (from app.js)

I might be thinking about this wrong, but how can I get the code in product.js to *reference* the code in app.js...similar to how the code in app.js references the code in vendors.js (rather than copying it in)?